# a.getAttribute("href") returns img src instead of a href

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, hyperlink, href, tagging

We've got a problem here: This small script should edit the href attribute of links if the href doesn't contain particutlar domains. Unfortunately when an `<a>` element contains an `<img>`, the JS will look for the image's `src` attribute, instead of the a's `href`.
Why is that? I just use getAttribute("href") on an `<a>`, not on an `<img>`?

It works if the `<a>` element does contain normal text instead of an `<img>`.

This is the JS:

```
var domains = ["mysite.com", "mysite2.com"];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++)
{
    var notFound = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < domains.length; k++) //iterate over all domains defined by user
    {
        var found = false;
        (elements[i].getAttribute("href").search(domains[k]) != -1) ? found = true : found = false; 
        if (!found) //not found
        {
            notFound++;
        }
    }
    if (notFound == domains.length) //link is outbound:
    {
        //Set link with outbound tracking parameter
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/38293729">
    <img width="100%" height="100%" src="http://mysite.com/images/fb_button.png"></img>
</a>
```

Can someone explain this behaviour and provide us with a tipp or a solution?
Thanks in advance

Jan

Comment: This link doesn't directly answer your question however it seems to demonstrate a good way to do what you are wanting to do here? http://wptheming.com/2012/01/tracking-outbound-links-with-google-analytics/

Comment: Thanks ak85. We aren't allowed to use jQuery. Thats the reason why we built it in pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It was of course an [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#PEBKAC) or [ID-10-T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#ID-10-T_Error) Error.

One of the links was:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/38293729/?utm_source=mysite.com&utm_medium=socialbutton&utm_campaign=socialbutton">
<img src="http://mysite.com/facebookbutton.png"></img>
</a>
```

Where it matched the URL parameter:

a href="http://facebook.com/38293729/?utm_source=***mysite.com***&utm_medium=socialbutton&utm_campaign=socialbutton"